# How to remove repetitive rows in MySQL when using JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this MySQL request:

```
SELECT * 
FROM candy 
RIGHT JOIN candytype ON candy.user_id = 1 AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id;
```

In my DB everything shows up but I see the same candy row showing twice because that one candy has two types. Is there a way that if it shows up once, that MySQL does not show it again in the result?

It just useless and I assume it makes my DB work more. I am just looking for a way to filter out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use DISTINCT.

```
SELECT DISTINCT candy.id, candy.name
FROM candy
RIGHT JOIN candytype
ON candy.user_id = 1
AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just any old type, you can do this (here I'm guessing at column names):

```
SELECT candy.id, candy.name, min(candytype.type)
FROM candy
RIGHT JOIN candytype
ON candy.user_id = 1
AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id GROUP BY candy.id;
```

If you want one row/candy, but you want to see all the types you can do:

```
SELECT candy.id, candy.name, GROUP_CONCAT(candytype.type)
FROM candy
RIGHT JOIN candytype
ON candy.user_id = 1
AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id GROUP BY candy.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions:

1. Use `WHERE` to filter out unwanted candy types.

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM candy
   RIGHT JOIN candytype ON candy.user_id = 1 AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id
   WHERE candytype.type = 'lolipop';
   ```
2. You might use a `GROUP BY` clause (but be careful with that, as it groups all rows containing same values, in this case having the same `user_id` and `candy_id`):

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM candy
   RIGHT JOIN candytype ON candy.user_id = 1 AND candytype.candy_id = candy.id
   GROUP BY candy.user_id, candytype.candy_id;
   ```